# Two divs side by side, one is scolling the other is fixed, but scroll a div if mouse is on fixed div too

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent div called with two child divs side by side. I want the right div scolling and the left one to be fixed.
Precisely, I want something exactly like this: https://venmo.com/about/product/

So far, here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="spec" style="height:700px">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 scrollable" style="height:700px;overflow-y:scroll">
      <section id="spec-text1" class="spec-text" style="height:400px">scrolling text in section1</section>
      <section id="spec-text1" class="spec-text" style="height:400px">scrolling text in section2</section>                                                       
      <section id="spec-text1" class="spec-text" style="height:400px">scrolling text in section3</section>                                                         
   </div>                                                                
   <div id="how-it-works" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center">        
   <img src="image_phone.png"/></div>
</div>
```

The issue is when mouse is over fixed div, the scrolling div stop scroll vertically! I want the scrolling div keeps scrolling if mouse is on another div too just like the sample above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want copy other template, please check DOM, css and the js first.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.phone{
    position: fixed; 
    top: 100px; 
    left: 0px; 
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="spec" >
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center">        
            <div class="phone">
                <img src="https://www.bell.ca/Styles/wireless/all_languages/all_regions/catalog_images/iPhone_7/iPhone7_MatBlk_lrg1_en.png"/>
            </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 " >
          <section id="spec-text1" class="spec-text" style="height:400px">scrolling text in section1</section>
          <section id="spec-text1" class="spec-text" style="height:400px">scrolling text in section2</section>
          <section id="spec-text1" class="spec-text" style="height:400px">scrolling text in section3</section>
          <section id="spec-text1" class="spec-text" style="height:400px">scrolling text in section3</section>
          <section id="spec-text1" class="spec-text" style="height:400px">scrolling text in section3</section>
          <section id="spec-text1" class="spec-text" style="height:400px">scrolling text in section3</section>
          <section id="spec-text1" class="spec-text" style="height:400px">scrolling text in section3</section>
       </div>                  
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Your question is only for that.

but your comment want more than that. so please next time provide a complete question, so you can prevent someone who want help you do work twice. (or maybe i just wrong to read your question)

> the key to copy/cloning template is just look at DOM, css and JS you
>   can copy that, analyze and see what is changed

here i will show you what i get from that template

1. open console. You will find `<div class="phone asset-feature-iphone">` with no inline element css at the beginning.
   [image]
2. when you start scroll. You will notice that `.phone` have inline css. So we can say: 1. there is a javascript who changed that. 2. they added css: `position: fixed` and `opacity:1`
   [image]
3. we scroll until the end. We will know that `.phone` still there. But we cant see that. because the opacity is same or below 0.
   [image]
4. we notice that event scroll is the trigger (just guessing now). To make sure, let's find the javascript. And we found `https://cdn1.venmo.com/production/js/auth-legacy.min.js`. we unminified with http://jsbeautifier.org/ , so we can read that. Then i find `scroll`, so i found scrollspy.

`..snippet..
}), define("auth-legacy/public/js/phone", ["jquery", "jquery-scrollspy"], function(e) {
..snippet..`

5. let's google this and we found https://github.com/softwarespot/jquery-scrollspy
6. try and try. demo : http://output.jsbin.com/xoyenamafe

what's i did is not exactly same with venmo.com because venmo.com run function on each `.spec-text` differently (change phone image, opacity, transform, etc). What i did is only show and hide phone image with opacity using 2nd last .spec-text as trigger.

good luck

Comment: Thank you plonknimbuzz for your help. The phone class is fixed relative to the all body. I want the phone image to be fixed relative to it's parent . I set position: relative to text-center and position: absolute to phone, but in that case scroll doesn't work when mouse is over phone!